# Set Laravel Application Urls

Tags: laravel-5

Fairly new to Laravel here and I'm struggling to understand how to make Laravel 5.2 aware of where it resides. Here's the issue:

I set up auth using `php artisan make:auth`, and can now see the lovely landing page, as well as login and register links in the menu. The problem is that these links don't go to the right place. They point to `/login` and `/register` in the code respectively, which translates into `http://localhost/login` or `http://localhost/register`. But since I'm not on a production site yet and am developing locally, my website resides at `http://localhost/projectname/public`.

I've gone into `config/app.php` and tried various values for the URL parameter, but these have no effect.

What can I do to get these links to reflect the full site URL, without manually entering it each time?

Answer (score 1):

you can run the development server in laravel using this command

`php artisan serve`

Did you try that?

Comment: That definitely works, and I'll accept as the answer if nobody can tell me how to get it to work on my existing server.

Comment: what is your existing server? are you on windows or linux?

Comment: xampp - cringe, I know, not the best I should use Homestead or something, but I've got xampp configured how I like it for now and it's a quick little project

Comment: hmm, I face problems in configuring laravel in xampp and wamp as well. But, on linux machine with a standalone apache2, I don't face any problem. Anyway, `http://localhost/projectname/public/login` and `http://localhost/projectname/public/register` should be working?

Comment: Yep, the pages definitely work, just not the links that should point to them.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have any solution related to configuring laravel app on WAMP or XAMPP. I have myself tried several times to override the http conf they provide but failed. So, I generally stick to the command for development, or configure the app on standalone apache2 on linux box, and finally have a similar setup at my prod server.

Comment: I believe the solution has to do with setting up a virtual host, of which I've had both successes and failures in the past, but currently I cannot set up virtual hosts without affecting the other sites I have running out of Xampp. If this is the case, I will switch to homestead for the project and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel url function:

```
{{ url().'/login' }}
```